# How do I control the timezone output of the date filter in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Let's assume I have an object saved to `$scope.person` as follows:

```
{name:"John",birthday:1381227352421}
```

In order to keep clean and universal, the server keeps all date/time stamps as universal from epoch.

When I display the object, I want to be able to do

```
<span>{{ person.birthday | date }}</span>
```

The above works just fine in presenting the *browser* local date/time, but I want it user-controlled, or perhaps I have different objects, each of which needs a different time presented.

How can I control the `date` filter so it presents for specific timezones?

EDIT: as requested, further explanation. I want to be able to do something like

```
<span>{{ person.birthday | date:'tz-'mytime }}</span>
```

Then I can have a pull-down where the user picks "EDT" or "UTC" or "PST" etc. When they do, the date of 1381227352421 is presented in the appropriate timezone.

Comment: not understand your question

Comment: unfotunetely that's how JS Date works. it's not an Angular problem (unless they have custom implementation of Date)

Comment: Hmm, @Aviatrix, good point. JS Date only supports outputting to UTC or local timezone, not controllable. I guess the answer is, "you can't", unless you use some other service.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is implement a custom directive. As you said, you'd like to have a selectbox/pulldown where the user selects its favourite timezone. This is DOM manipulation, right ? And DOM manipulation, in AngularJS, should always been done in a directive.

A directive that would look like that :

```
<timezonechooser data='birth'></timezonechooser>
```

Here's a simple Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Bm2Mh/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I meant, does Angular have built-in support to do timezone filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [angular-moment](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-moment) ?

Comment: I had not seen it. In the end, I used momentjs with moment-timezone and built customer directives